# What's the best method for fetch the huge files from the webserver using c#

Tags: c#-4.0

Hi i have a spec for fetch the files from server and predict the un-used files from the directory in this situation i am going to fetch the files from server it will return huge files, the problem is the cpu usage will increase while i am fetching large files, so i like to eliminate this scenario. can any one knows how to avoid this situation please share with me though it might help full for me.
Thanks

Comment: there's usually a lot of I/O when fetching hughe files but that would mean there's little CPU uasage. So what exactly is your problem. Are you processing the files and need a way to parallelize this? or are you looking for ways to asyncronously read files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your large file on server into several smaller pieces and fetch some metadata about amount of pieces, size etc. and than fetch them one by one from your client `c#` code and join pieces in binary mode to your larger file.